# Pass a object from Select in Thyemleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have the following class:

```
public class Person {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "person_id")
   private int personId;

   @Column(name = "person_name", unique = true)
   private String personName;

   @Column(name = "gender")
   private Gender personGender;
}
```

Here is Gender as well:

```
public class Gender{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "gender_id")
   private int genderId;

   @Column(name = "gender_name", unique = true)
   private String genderName;
}
```

I've assembled a Thymelef dropdown menu when creating a new Person that looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = ("/newPerson"), method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView createPerson() {
      ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

      Person person= new Person ();
      model.addObject("person", person);

      List<Gender> genders= genderService.getAll();
      model.addObject("genders", genders);

      model.setViewName("user/newPerson");

      return model;
   }
```

(I realize it looks kinda dumb, but it is a simplified version of my code.)

And here is the HTML:

```
<form class="form-createNew" role="form" method="POST" 
  th:action="@{/newPerson}" th:object="${person}">

   <div class="form-row">
     <div class="col">
       <div class="form-label-group">
          <input type="text" th:field="*{personName}" id="personName" class="form-control" placeholder="Person name">
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-row">
     <div class="col">
       <div class="form-label-group">
         <select th:field="*{personGender}" class="form-control" 
            id="personGender" name="personGender">
           <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select gender</option>
           <option th:each="gender: ${genders}"
                   th:value="${gender.genderId}"
                   th:text="${gender.genderName}"></option>
         </select>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    <button id="registerBtn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block shadow-none text-uppercase" type="submit"> Create </button>
    </form>
```

And finally my question:

What I am receiving at the POST method in the controller for /newPerson is a Person object with the value from the input field, but NULL for the Gender. What is causing that and where am I wrong here? I went through similar questions on SO regarding that issue and also the Thymeleaf Docs/Baeldung and everything looks okay to me.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: If you're binding genderId, shouldn't it look like: `th:field="*{personGender.genderId}"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending for your post controller something like this:

> personGender: gernderId

You must do:

> personGender.genderId : genderId

For that use in your html:

> th:field="*{personGender.genderId}"

instead of

> th:field="*{personGender}"

I think it will help you!